# google analytics, traffic from 3rd party apps

Tags: android, iphone, google-analytics

It seems traffic from mobile app (clicking a link from mobile app) is listed as `direct`

Suppose we run ad campaign on two apps and want to differentiate where of the two user came from.
Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the third party apps allow you to place GET parameters in the url link you could test for them. have your ads link to example.com?site=app1 and example.com?site=app2 and simply log an event as event category app1 or app2.

if they don't allow you to have GET parameters than i think the only way would be to link to different pages.